# Discrepancy on the value of $\phi(v)$ in Einstein's 'On the Electrodynamics of moving bodies'?

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, lorentz-symmetry

On Einstein's derivation of the Lorentz Transformation he obtains the differential equation
$$\dfrac{\partial \tau}{\partial x'}+\dfrac{v}{c^2-v^2}\dfrac{\partial\tau}{\partial t}=0$$

From this is obtained
$$\tau=a\left(t-\dfrac{v}{c^2-v^2}x'\right)$$
Where a is described as being an unknown function of $v$ $\phi(v)$. As one derives this, it is pretty clear that $a=\dfrac{\partial \tau}{\partial t}$. Einstein then proceeds to derive the Lorentz transformations as
\begin{align}
\tau &= \phi(v) \beta (t - \frac{vx}{c^2})\tag{1}\\
\xi &= \phi(v) \beta (x - v t)\tag{2}\\
\eta &= \phi(v) y\\
\zeta &= \phi(v) z
\end{align}
Where $$\beta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
It is clear that to arrive to these equations he had to modify the value of $\phi(v)$ from $\phi(v)=a$ to $\phi(v)=a\beta$, otherwise equations 1 and 2 would have a $\beta^2$ term in them instead of $\beta$. This leaves the value of $\phi(v)$ as $$\phi(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\dfrac{\partial \tau}{\partial t}$$
Further down the paper, it is determined that $$\phi(v)=1$$
Thus leaving the previous equations as $$\tau =  \beta \left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2}\right)$$ $$\xi =  \beta (x - v t)$$ $$\eta = y$$ $$\zeta =  z$$ 
Since it has previously been shown that $\phi(v)$ should equal $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\dfrac{\partial \tau}{\partial t}$, then $$\phi(v)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}\dfrac{\partial}{\partial t}\frac{t - \frac{vx}{c^2}}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}}$$
But this results in $$\phi(v)=\frac{1}{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}$$ which contradicts the previous result which states that $\phi(v)=1$ 
How can this be accounted for? Is there something I am missing?

Comment: First of all you are missing a square root in the definition of $\beta$. But look closely at the r.h.s. of $$\tau=a\left(t-\dfrac{v}{c^2-v^2}x'\right)$$vs. $$\tau = \phi(v) \beta \left(t - \frac{vx}{c^2} \right)$$One is a function of $t$ and $x'$, the other of $t$ and $x$. The factor of $\beta$ arises naturally on "Substituting for $x'$ its value" (quote from relevant paragraph), which from the text turns out to be $x'= x - vt$. Also, check out the derivative when you take $\tau$ as a function of $t$ and $x'$, where $x'$ is in turn a function of $t$ and $x$.